# The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceNameType' - The Enumeration constaint failed

Tags: vb.net, wcf

[image: The warning I get]

I created a WCF service application in VS 2015. Deleted the default IService1.vb and Service1.scv files, and added WCF Service that added new files to the project. I then updated the web.config file as in the attached snapshot. The service name flags a warning as in the subject, and on the snapshot. When I view in browser I get this server error: The type 'WcfNsAPI.ServiceNsRest', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

I searched for this error and found out that the fix is relative. In my case, I really don't know what to do. Any suggestions to resolve this error?
I use ADO.NET Entity Data Model to connect to the sql database, if that helps.

Comment: When I changed the name attribute from "WcfNsAPI.ServiceNsRest" to "WcfNsAPI.WcfNsAPI.ServiceNsRest", the warning flag disappears but the error in the browser persist.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated the project by following the same steps and the new one works. I can't tell what was wrong with the first project.

Doing something over and over sometimes yields different results.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was using the wrong case for the service name attribute. It is case sensitive.